# AngularJS showing the first item from the list in IE11 when any item is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

When I select an item that is not the first one in the list, IE11 on Windows 7/8 shows the first. If I re-select, the problem goes away. It only occurs once after the page load. I have not tested in older versions of IE.

I tried the code with older versions of AngularJS as well. Same code behaves as expected in Chrome.

Is this a problem with IE or is there a known workaround for this? Or is it a problem with the code?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/2.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select data-ng-model="selecteditem" data-ng-options="item for item in items"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  $scope.selecteditem = "";
});
```

Setting selected item value doesn't seem to work for array of objects.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select data-ng-model="selecteditem" data-ng-options="item.name for item in items"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{name:'item1'}, {name:'item2'}, {name:'item3'}];
  $scope.selecteditem = {name:'item1'};
});
```

Here is the showing the behavior http://plnkr.co/edit/ojAhTP50iHS030tezhQ3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that solution for you please see her:http://plnkr.co/edit/imjLXBmGpZReZ63KNWlg?p=preview ?

```
<select data-ng-model="selecteditem" data-ng-options="item for item in items">
          <option style="display:none" value=""></option>

        </select>
```

In case you want to use array of objects you need to initialize selected option by reference to the same object

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{name:'item1'}, {name:'item2'}, {name:'item3'}];
  $scope.selecteditem = $scope.items[0];
});
```

please see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/f9NtvG2tYKx93iZJT44J?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. It also forces me to select an item by default.

Comment: Thanks. I will check if the solution will work for the second code sample where the array is of objects.

Comment: Yes. That will work except that it forces the selection of one item which is a different behavior than in Chrome. I will wait until Monday and accept this as answer if nothing else comes up. I should be able to insert a dummy entry that could be selected by default. I have up voted this answer for now. Thank you for your time.